# Populate Grid view drop down from another grid view text boxes asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, event-handling

I am having a Form which has gridview1.we can add multiple rows by clicking on Add row button as attached image.I have to bind a dropdown in another gridview2 based on value of textboxes of gridview1(Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4).If textbox values (eg:- name1) gets changed then value of dropdown in gridview2 should be refreshed.As of now i am using asp.net gridviews.

what approach can be considered to get it fulfilled?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code please

Comment: I am looking for suggestions/approach to get it done.how feasible it is